# Are Rhythmbox preferences gone?

Tags: 18.04, rhythmbox

[image: Screenshot of Rhythmbox, showing an empty Play Queue]

Is it me, or does Rhythmbox not have a preferences dialog anymore? And does this mean there is no way anymore to [change the format for audio CD extraction](https://www.maketecheasier.com/rip-audio-cd-in-linux/) from the default (OGG Vorbis)?